# Несколько View Resolver для выбора View из контроллера

Tags: spring, java

1. Можно ли сделать, а если можно то как, следующее. Создать несколько view resolver например, один для jsp, один для velocity, чтобы из контроллера можно было выбрать, какой из них использовать. Например, есть запрос `/adress?view=vm` - используется view velocity, а если `/adress?view=jsp`, то соответственно jsp. Это выдуманный пример, просто интересно как это сделать :)
2. Как правильно сделать ответ на запрос скажем в виде JSON или XML? Правильно ли для этого использовать @ResponseBody и просто отдавать строку?

Спасибо.

Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

1. Не знаю? Наверняка можно)
2. Попробуйте использовать Jackson и отдавать в качевстве ResponseBody объекты, листы, мапы и т.д.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/